# git submodules and branches

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

So my structure looks like this for a repo:

```
   --project - master
   --project - beta
   --project - dev1.0
   --project - dev1.1
   --project - dev1.2
```

Currently I do `git branch` and I am on `dev1.2` which is fine, I want to add a project reference starting at 1.2 and then "merge" it all the way back to master (or the other way around, which ever is better) the problem is, [according to this book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules), that I don't think I understand this enough.

Could I just do, on the dev1.2 branch:

`git add submodule --link-- name` then do `git commit -a -m "some message"` and `git checkout dev1.1` then `git cherry-pick #commit where I added the reference project` and finally `git submodule udpate`??

This would essentially say: *on dev 1.2 add a new reference, commit it - adding the reference - switch to 1.1 where there is no reference, cherry pick the commit to add the reference and then update the submodule to now have the reference on both 1.2 and 1.1* ..

Answer (score 0):

Managing submodules could get really messy, fast. I would recommend using [`git-repo`](http://code.google.com/p/git-repo/) instead. It was created by Android open source project to fulfill Android needs, but it is very generic mechanism that can be used by any project. It is much more versatile compared to git submodules, and integrates really well with [`gerrit code review`](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) (however this is optional).

git-repo allows you to use both "track by commit sha" model (equivalent to git submodule) or "track by branch name" model (impossible with git submodule), or any combination of them.

There is only one downside to repo - it does not explicitly support Windows (but works great on Linux, Mac and most POSIX systems). Original reason why it did not work on Windows was that it makes extensive use of symbolic links, but Windows XP does not support them. Since Windows 7+ supports symbolic links, it should be possible to fix `git-repo` to work on Windows, but unfortunately nobody bothered to do so, yet.

Comment: This is fine all my code is done in linux, thank god - death to windows. So this allows me to "bring" another repository in to my code base and use it as a "reference" can I ship that other project with this one or is it all "stubbed out" thus if I try and ship it will be like "your missing these files... " (it being the super project using the sub project)